# Convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to double or int swift

Tags: swift, int, type-conversion, cllocationcoordinate2d

how would I convert a CLLocationcoordiante to a double so that I can perorrm arithmetic on it and compare coordinates using their size?
In (swift for ios)

Comment: I knew they were a form of double, I just expected to have to convert them directly to 'double'. When the compiler started throwing "CLLocationcoordinate 2D is not convertible to double", I thought my understanding was totally flawed. I never tried coordinate +/-/* etc x because I thought that was too simple.. My bad!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is struct of `latitude` and `longitude` both defined as `CLLocationDegrees` which itself is a typealias of `double`.

The following code creates a location in code, but it could also be supplied by a MapKit function:

```
var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.30, longitude: 44.34)
```

You now can access the values by calling `location.latitude` and `location.longitude`.